# How to get the quantity of color options of each configurable product

Tags: configurable-product, color-swatches

I need to know the number of color options of each configurable product in a list. I get them like this:

```
    $productAttributeOptions = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($_product);

//in this case the attribute color that I needed is in [0] position
$available_colors = sizeof($productAttributeOptions[0]["values"]);

if ($available_colors >1):
    //custom code
endif;
```

The problem is that for one product works fine, but for 20 or more it is really slow, it takes too long to load each page of products list.

Is there a fastest way to do it? I see that my way is not a really good way.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution, maybe it is not the best one, but it is pretty fast compared to the one I was using:

```
$_idsForTheQuery = $_productCollection->getAllIds();

    $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $sql_query = "SELECT parent_id, COUNT(parent_id) AS colors FROM
                (SELECT cpr.parent_id FROM `eav_attribute` a
                LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` cpei ON cpei.attribute_id=a.attribute_id
                LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_relation` cpr ON cpr.child_id=cpei.entity_id
                WHERE attribute_code = 'color' AND cpr.parent_id IN (".implode (", ", $_idsForTheQuery).") 
                GROUP BY cpr.parent_id, cpei.value) colors 
                GROUP BY parent_id";

    $results = $read->query($sql_query);

    $number_of_colors_by_id_array = array();
    foreach($results as $r)
    {
        $number_of_colors_by_id_array[$r["parent_id"]] = $r["colors"];
    }
```

and then in the foreach loop of the products

```
<?php if ($number_of_colors_by_id_array[$_product->getId()]>1): ?>
    <div class="aditional-colors-message">
        <?php echo __('more colors available'); ?>        
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Maybe it helps somebody.